# Как добавить в Android проект операционную систему iOS в Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

у меня есть готовый проект для OS Android, можно ли как-нибудь добавить в данный проект решение для OS iOS или данный вопрос можно будет решить только созданием нового проекта и копированием всей информации из прошлого проекта?

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то проекты для iOS должны создаваться из-под Mac'а. Вы подключаетесь к своему Mac'у с помощью открытого удаленного доступа (в инете есть инфа, как его включить), и в Visual Studio он должен отображаться, как Debug-устройство. Если я ошибаюсь, остальные меня поправят.

Если про перенос - скорее всего придется что-то допиливать, и полностью перенести проект на iOS, запилив его изначально под Android не выйдет